# Parse Json array in android / java file

Tags: java, android, json

I am facing a problem to reach to an object which is inside an array of another object of another array. To make it simpler i am attaching the image (attached below), basically i want to reach to json object "0" inside jsonarray ticket itmes.

my codes are

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(buffer.toString());
 JSONObject jsonobject = null;

 jsonobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

 JSONArray jsonarray1 = new JSONArray(buffer.toString());

 jsonarray1 = jsonobject.getJSONArray("ticketitems");



 JSONObject jsonobject1 = null;

  TicketItem ticketItemList = new TicketItem();

  jsonobject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

  ticketItemList.setItemCount(jsonobject1.getInt("itemCount"));

  TicketItemList.add(ticketItemList);
```

However, jsonarray1 generates an exception stating

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for ticketitems
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kRtS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's case sensitive. It should be

```
jsonarray1 = jsonobject.getJSONArray("ticketItems");
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
jsonarray1 = jsonobject.getJSONArray("ticketitems");
```

with

```
jsonarray1 = jsonobject.getJSONArray("ticketItems");
```